# Choosing between Time-Series and Collection Container in GridDB for Efficient Internet Data Usage Notifications

Tags: sql, griddb

I am working on a project that involves implementing notifications for internet data usage using GridDB as the database solution. I am currently in the process of deciding whether to use the Time-Series or Collection Container in GridDB for optimal performance in handling and querying data related to internet usage.

Here are the key aspects I'm considering:

**Real-time Notifications:** I need to efficiently store and query data to provide real-time notifications for internet data usage spikes or specific events.
**Performance Concerns:** Considering the nature of internet data usage, I am concerned about the performance implications of choosing between Time-Series and Collection Container. I want to make sure that the selected option can handle high-throughput scenarios efficiently.

Here's a simplified example of what I have in mind:

```
InternetDataUsage
| timestamp          | long (TIMESTAMP)   |
| usage              | long (LONG)        |
| device_id          | string (STRING)    |
| notification_sent  | bool (BOOL)        |
```

Your valuable insights and code examples will be highly appreciated. Thank you!